# Django Stripe payment does not respond after clicking the Submit Payment button

Tags: python, django, heroku, stripe-payments

I have an e-commerce application that I'm working on. The app is currently hosted on Heroku free account. At the moment I can select a product, add it on the cart and can get up to the stripe form and type in the card details, but when I click the 'Submit Payment' button nothing happens. I don't even get an error message. I'm using Stripe test keys and 4242 four times as my card number. Can anyone help me to find out what's going on pliz. I have been stuck on it for days.

Here is the relevant code below:

Settings.py code:

```
from .base import *
import dj_database_url

DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'}
]

""" DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
 """

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLIC_KEY')
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "us-east-2"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')


# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

# The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]

# The URL to use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

views.py (Specifically the class PaymentView(View)):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, View
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Q
from .forms import CheckoutForm, CouponForm, RefundForm, PaymentForm
from .models import Item, OrderItem, Order, Address, Payment, Coupon, Refund, UserProfile

import random
import string
import stripe
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        if order.billing_address:
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': False
            }
            userprofile = self.request.user.userprofile
            if userprofile.one_click_purchasing:
                # fetch the users card list
                cards = stripe.Customer.list_sources(
                    userprofile.stripe_customer_id,
                    limit=3,
                    object='card'
                )
                card_list = cards['data']
                if len(card_list) > 0:
                    # update the context with the default card
                    context.update({
                        'card': card_list[0]
                    })
            return render(self.request, "payment.html", context)
        else:
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "You have not added a billing address")
            return redirect("core:checkout")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        form = PaymentForm(self.request.POST)
        print('form')
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('stripeToken')
            # print('token')
            save = form.cleaned_data.get('save')
            use_default = form.cleaned_data.get('use_default')

            if save:
                if userprofile.stripe_customer_id != '' and userprofile.stripe_customer_id is not None:
                    customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(
                        userprofile.stripe_customer_id)
                    customer.sources.create(source=token)

                else:
                    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                        email=self.request.user.email,
                    )
                    customer.sources.create(source=token)
                    userprofile.stripe_customer_id = customer['id']
                    userprofile.one_click_purchasing = True
                    userprofile.save()

            amount = order.get_total() * 100

            try:

                if use_default or save:
                    # charge the customer because we cannot charge the token more than once
                    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                        amount=amount,  # cents
                        currency="usd",
                        customer=userprofile.stripe_customer_id
                    )
                else:
                    # charge once off on the token
                    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                        amount=amount,  # cents
                        currency="usd",
                        source=token
                    )

                # create the payment
                payment = Payment()
                payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
                payment.user = self.request.user
                payment.amount = order.get_total()
                payment.save()

                # assign the payment to the order

                order_items = order.items.all()
                order_items.update(ordered=True)
                for item in order_items:
                    item.save()

                order.ordered = True
                order.payment = payment
                order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
                order.save()

                messages.success(self.request, "Your order was successful!")
                return redirect("/")

            except stripe.error.CardError as e:
                body = e.json_body
                err = body.get('error', {})
                messages.warning(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
                return redirect("/")

            except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
                # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
                print(e)
                messages.warning(self.request, "Rate limit error")
                return redirect("/")

            except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
                # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
                print(e)
                messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid parameters")
                return redirect("/")

            except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
                # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
                # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
                print(e)
                messages.warning(self.request, "Not authenticated")
                return redirect("/")

            except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
                # Network communication with Stripe failed
                print(e)
                messages.warning(self.request, "Network error")
                return redirect("/")

            except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
                # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
                # yourself an email
                print(e)
                messages.warning(
                    self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please try again.")
                return redirect("/")

            except Exception as e:
                # send an email to ourselves
                print(e)
                messages.warning(
                    self.request, "A serious error occurred. We have been notifed.")
                return redirect("/")

        messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid data received")
        return redirect("/payment/stripe/")
```

payment.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_head %}
<style>
  #stripeBtnLabel {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-variant: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
  }

  #stripeBtn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #32325d;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease;
    float: left;
    width: 100%
  }

  button:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    background-color: #43458b;
  }

  .stripe-form {
    padding: 5px 30px;
  }

  #card-errors {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    color: #fa755a;
  }

  .stripe-form-row {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  /**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
  .StripeElement {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    height: 40px;

    padding: 10px 12px;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
    transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  }

  .StripeElement--focus {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
  }

  .StripeElement--invalid {
    border-color: #fa755a;
  }

  .StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fefde5 !important;
  }

  .current-card-form {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
{% endblock extra_head %}

{% block content %}

<main>
  <div class="container wow fadeIn">

    <h2 class="my-5 h2 text-center">Payment</h2>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
        <div class="card">

          <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
          {% if card %}
          <div style="padding: 5px 30px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="use_default_card" id="use_default_card">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="use_default_card">Use default card:
                **** **** **** {{ card.last4 }}
                <span>Exp: {{ card.exp_month }}/{{ card.exp_year }}</span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endif %}

          <div class="current-card-form">
            <form action="." method="post" class="stripe-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="use_default" value="true">
              <div class="stripe-form-row">
                <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
              </div>
              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="new-card-form">
            <form action="." method="post" class="stripe-form" id="stripe-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="stripe-form-row" id="creditCard">
                <label for="card-element" id="stripeBtnLabel">
                  Credit or debit card
                </label>
                <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
                  <div class="__PrivateStripeElement"
                    style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;">
                    <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5"
                      allowpaymentrequest="true"
                      src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-19066928f2ed1ba3ffada645e45f5b50.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;keyMode=test&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1"
                      title="Secure payment input frame"
                      style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 19.2px;"></iframe><input
                      class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false"
                      maxlength="1"
                      style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="stripe-form-row">
                <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
              </div>
              <div class="stripe-form-row">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="save" id="save_card_info">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="save_card_info">Save for future purchases
                    {{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }} {{ STRIPE_SECRET_KEY }}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      {% include "order_snippet.html" %}

    </div>

  </div>
</main>

{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_scripts %}

<script nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

  var currentCardForm = $('.current-card-form');
  var newCardForm = $('.new-card-form');
  var use_default_card = document.querySelector("input[name=use_default_card]");
  use_default_card.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      newCardForm.hide();
      currentCardForm.show()
    } else {
      newCardForm.show();
      currentCardForm.hide()
    }
  })

</script>

{% endblock extra_scripts %}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? Is your HTTP request on form submission making it out to your server endpoint? Add additional logging statements or breakpoints to learn how far you are getting in your code. For e.g., is `createToken()` being called? Is it resolving with a `result`? Basically, try to debug how far your code is getting and that would help us identify what to look into further.

Comment: Add breakpoints or `console.log`s to your code to help with debugging this and breaking down the problem to narrow down where the issue is

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I thought of doing it but I'm not using the local machine. It is hosted on Heroku. Do you think console.log would still work? Plus there aren't any error in the browser. Also can you suggest a way to check that the HTTP request is making it to the server endpoint.

Comment: you would have to set up locally to debug. Was it ever working locally as expected? About your second point, when you run locally, adding log statements inside your endpoint would help you identify if it is being reached or not. Heroku also has logs (for the server logs atleast) but setting up locally and debugging is the best way here

Comment: `console.log`s should still work even if you're running off Heroku, those should be logging out in your browser. By adding logs, you want to track the path that your code is taking and how far it is getting, that would help you identify what isn't working

Comment: I get a "POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens 401" error in the browser console. Do you what might be causing it?

Comment: this is helpful, so a request is going out to Stripe but a 401 highlights an unauthorized access i.e. no valid API key provided.
Debug your code to make sure your publishable key is being set to Stripe.js. I can see in your code that it is but logging it out and making sure it is set would help.

Comment: I suspect it must have something to do with the JS code because I also get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):449" error. I did little search on it, I see people talk about making sure you're loading jquery and bootstrap in your base template before the {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}. I'm lost I dunno what to do

Comment: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null -> this means you're grabbing reference to a HTML DOM element with `document.getElementById` or similar, but it doesn't exist so you're getting `null`. Then you're trying to add an eventListener to that `null`. I'd start looking which element you're adding an event listener to and why its coming out `null`. Most likely, you're using the wrong ID to reference that HTML element

Comment: I actually already solved this issue long ago. Sorry not to have come back to you when I did. It was about the API key not being passed properly from the view to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the API key along with other variables in the context variable by adding:

```
'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY': settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
```

inside the context variable.

Comment: Where is the context variable?