# Django Stripe Payment Responds with Invalid Parameter after clicking Submit Payment button

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, stripe-payments

I am working on an e-commerce project that requires stripe payment gateway. It is my first time to work on an application that requires stripe payment. I am a junior programmer. I am working on my localhost machine, I have tried to debug the code but i have failed to see where the problem is. @Hacker86 got the solution but has not shared it can anyone help me with the problem.
This is the link of the same problem [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161406/django-stripe-payment-does-not-respond-after-clicking-the-submit-payment-button)

I tried to solve the problem with the solution in the replies to above the question but all was in veil. So please can anyone help immediately reply me.

Below is my relevant Code

base.py

```
import os
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_countries',

    'core',


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'perfectfits.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'perfectfits.wsgi.application'



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')


# Auth

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)


SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# CRISPY FORMS

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, View
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import CheckoutForm, CouponForm, RefundForm
from .models import Item, OrderItem, Order, BillingAddress, Payment, Coupon, Refund

import random
import string
import stripe
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


def create_ref_code():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=20))


# Create your views here.

def products(request):
    context = {
        'items': Item.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "products.html")

class CheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            form = CheckoutForm()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'couponform': CouponForm(),
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': True
                }
            return render(self.request, "checkout.html", context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.info(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:checkout")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            if form.is_valid():
                street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
                apartment_address = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment_address')
                country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
                zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')
                # TODO: add functionality for these fields
                # same_shipping_address = form.cleaned_data.get('same_shipping_address')
                # save_info = form.cleaned_data.get('save_info')
                payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')
                billing_address = BillingAddress(
                    user=self.request.user,
                    street_address=street_address,
                    apartment_address=apartment_address,
                    country=country,
                    zip=zip
                )
                billing_address.save()
                order.billing_address = billing_address
                order.save()

                if payment_option == 'S':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='stripe')
                elif payment_option =='P':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='paypal')
                elif payment_option =='M':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='mobilemoney')
                else:
                    messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid payment option selected")
                    return redirect('core:checkout')
            
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")


class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # order
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        if order.billing_address:
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': False,
                'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY' : settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
            }
            return render(self.request, "payment.html", context)
        else:
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "You have not added a billing address")
            return redirect("core:checkout")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount = order.get_total()


        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount, # cents
                currency="ugx",
                source=token
            )


            # create the payment
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = order.get_total()
            payment.save()

            # Assign the payment to the order

            order_items = order.items.all()
            order_items.update(ordered=True)
            for item in order_items:
                item.save()

            order.ordered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
            order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "Your order was successful!")
            return redirect("/")
            
        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.warning(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.warning(self.request,"Rate limit error")
            return redirect("/")
            

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid parameters")
            return redirect("/")
            

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.warning(self.request, "Not authenticated")
            return redirect("/")
            

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.warning(self.request, "Network error")
            return redirect("/")
            

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            messages.warning(self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please try again")
            return redirect("/")
            

        except Exception as e:
            # Send an email to ourselves
            messages.warning(self.request, "A serious error occurred. We have been notified")
            return redirect("/")
            





class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"


class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")
    


class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
        )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False) # qs is query set
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your Cart.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your Cart.")
        return redirect("core:order-summary")



@login_required
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, 
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your Cart.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart.")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order.")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)

    


@login_required
def remove_single_item_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, 
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            if order_item.quantity > 1:
                order_item.quantity -= 1
                order_item.save()
            else:
                order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart.")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order.")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)

def get_coupon(request, code):
    
    try:
        coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code=code)
        return coupon
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        messages.info(request, "This Coupon does not exist")
        return redirect("core:checkout")

class AddCouponView(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CouponForm(self.request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                code = form.cleaned_data.get('code')
                order = Order.objects.get(
                    user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
                order.coupon = get_coupon(self.request, code)
                order.save()
                messages.success(self.request, "Successfully added coupon")
                return redirect("core:checkout")

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                messages.info(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
                return redirect("core:checkout")


class RequestRefundView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RefundForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(self.request, "request_refund.html", context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RefundForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ref_code = form.cleaned_data.get('ref_code')
            message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            # edit the order
            try:
                order = Order.objects.get(ref_code=ref_code)
                order.refund_requested = True
                order.save()

            
                # store the refund
                refund = Refund()
                refund.order = order
                refund.reason = message
                refund.email = email
                refund.save()

                messages.info(self.request, "Your request was received.")
                return redirect("core:request-refund")

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                messages.info(self.request, "This order does not exist.")
                return redirect("core:request-refund")
```

payment.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_head %}
<style>

#stripeBtnLabel {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
}

#stripeBtn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #32325d;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background-color: #43458b;
}

.stripe-form {
  padding: 5px 30px;
}

#card-errors {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fa755a;
}

.stripe-form-row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 40px;

  padding: 10px 12px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}

.current-card-form {
  display: none;
}

</style>
{% endblock extra_head %}

{% block content %}

  <main >
    <div class="container wow fadeIn">

      <h2 class="my-5 h2 text-center">Payment</h2>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <div class="card">

            {% if card %}
              <div style="padding: 5px 30px;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="use_default_card" id="use_default_card">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="use_default_card">Use default card:
                    **** **** **** {{ card.last4 }} 
                  <span>Exp: {{ card.exp_month }}/{{ card.exp_year }}</span></label>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="current-card-form">
              <form action="." method="post" class="stripe-form">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="hidden" name="use_default" value="true">
                  <div class="stripe-form-row">
                    <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
                  </div>
                  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div class="new-card-form">
              <form action="." method="post" class="stripe-form" id="stripe-form">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="stripe-form-row" id="creditCard">
                      <label for="card-element" id="stripeBtnLabel">
                          Credit or debit card
                      </label>
                      <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty"><div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-19066928f2ed1ba3ffada645e45f5b50.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;keyMode=test&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 19.2px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="stripe-form-row">
                    <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="stripe-form-row">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="save" id="save_card_info">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="save_card_info">Save for future purchases</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        {% include "order_snippet.html" %}

      </div>

    </div>
  </main>

{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_scripts %}

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('{{STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}}');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

  var currentCardForm = $('.current-card-form');
  var newCardForm = $('.new-card-form');
  var use_default_card = document.querySelector("input[name=use_default_card]");
  use_default_card.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      newCardForm.hide();
      currentCardForm.show()
    } else {
      newCardForm.show();
      currentCardForm.hide()
    }
  })

</script>

{% endblock extra_scripts %}
```

Comment: The stack overflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161406/django-stripe-payment-does-not-respond-after-clicking-the-submit-payment-button) you linked to is completely different - they were missing 'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY' in their context. I'm guessing the error is coming from the Charge creation request. What value are you using for `amount`?

Comment: @karbi i am using the total amount; `amount = order.get_total()`

Comment: Yes, but what is the actual integer that `amount` equals? I'm curious because UGX is treated as a special case by Stripe (due to backwards compatability) and needs to be divisible by 100. https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#special-cases

Comment: Could you also share the exact error you're getting when clicking the Submit button?

Comment: my actual amount was 750000

Comment: @karbi there was no error in the terminal, but i had invalid parameters as the message

Comment: Since it looks like `amount` and `currency` are both valid, I would log `token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')` and make sure you're getting the right value.